# How to find the longest path between 2 vertices in igraph?

Tags: r

Assume having the following R code :

```
# create an example graph
library(igraph)
g <- graph.tree(n = 10, children = 2)

# add edge weights
E(g)$weight <- sample(1:10, length(E(g)), replace = TRUE)

# find the shortest path and its cost
shortest_path <- shortest_paths(g, from = 1, to = 10, output = "both")$epath[[1]]
cost <- sum(get.edge.attribute(g, "weight", index = shortest_path))

# print the results
cat(paste("Shortest path:", paste(shortest_path, collapse = " -> "), "\n"))
cat(paste("Cost:", cost, "\n"))
```

How can I find the longest path between 1 and 10 ?

Comment: Please be aware that this is generally not an [easy (or even possible)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) thing to do. What type of graph are you dealing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
To get longest path from cost / weight point of view:

```
path_costs <- lapply(all_paths, function(path) sum(E(g, path)$weight))
longest_path_index <- which.max(path_costs) 
longest_path <- all_paths[[longest_path_index]] 
cost <- path_costs[longest_path_index] 

cat(paste("Longest path:", paste(longest_path, collapse = " -> "), "\n")) 
cat(paste("Cost:", cost, "\n"))
```

**First answer:**
We could use `get.all.shortest.paths()` function to finally select the path with the maximum length:

```
all_shortest <- get.all.shortest.paths(g, from = 1, to = 10, mode = "out")


longest_path <- all_shortest[[which.max(sapply(shortest_paths, length))]]
cost <- sum(get.edge.attribute(g, "weight", index = longest_path))

cat(paste("Longest path:", paste(longest_path, collapse = " -> "), "\n"))
cat(paste("Cost:", cost, "\n"))
```

Comment: Hello TarJae , i´m searching longest path from cost / weight point of view. A possible solution could be using all_paths(from , to ) function , and use lapply combined with which to get longest_path

Comment: Maybe something like this: `path_costs <- lapply(all_paths, function(path) sum(E(g, path)$weight))
longest_path_index <- which.max(path_costs)
longest_path <- all_paths[[longest_path_index]]
cost <- path_costs[longest_path_index]
cat(paste("Longest path:", paste(longest_path, collapse = " -> "), "\n"))
cat(paste("Cost:", cost, "\n"))`